# Opencart compare table widths not equal

Tags: php, opencart

I've just noticed a small issue with my Opencart website which I was hoping someone could help solve.

Basically when items are compared (up to 4) they are added to the table at http://www.imbued.co.uk/compare but the table widths are never equal no matter how many items are in there. I'm new to coding so please let me know what code you might need to see to get a better idea of the dynamics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your stylesheet.css of this template add the following line

```
.compare-info td {
  width: 20%
}
```

this's how the oc default template does it, even when there are less than 4 products, tables looks equally spaced.

As an alternative you can determine how many products are there for compare, and then set td width dynamically using js. if there are N products set td width to 100/(N+1) %